# Looping multiple arrays

Tags: ruby

I have an array containing multiple arrays (the number may vary) of significant dimensions (an array may contain up to 150 objects).

With the array, I need to find a combination (one element for each sub-array) that matches a condition.

Due to the dimensions, I tried to use `Enumerator::Lazy` as follows

```
catch :match do
   array[0].product(*array[1..-1]).lazy.each do |combination|
    throw :match if ConditionMatcher.match(combination)
  end
end
```

However, I realize when I call `each` the enumerator is evaluated and it performs very slowly.
I have tried to replace `each` with methods included in `Enumerator::Lazy` such as `take_while`

```
 array[0].product(*array[1..-1]).lazy.take_while do |combination|
  return false if ConditionMatcher.match(combination)
 end
```

But also, in this case, the `product` is evaluated with low performance.

For better performance, even id I don't really like it, I'm thinking to replace `product` with a nested `each` loop. Something like

```
catch :match do
 array[0].each do |first|
   array[1].each do |second|
     array[2].each do |third|
       throw :match if ConditionMatcher.match([first, second, third])
     end
   end
 end
end
```

Due to the fact that the number of sub-arrays changes from time to time. I'm not sure how to implement it.

Moreover, is there a better way to loop through all the sub-arrays without loading the entire set of combinations?

- Update 1 -

Each sub-array contains an `ActiveRecord::Relation` on a polymorphic association. Therefore, each element of each combination responds to the same 2 methods (`start_time` and `end_time`) each returning an instance of `Time`.

The matcher checks if all the objects in the combination don't have overlapping times.

Comment: Can you give some example of the inputs and the expected arguments to the `ConditionMatcher.match`?

Comment: See Update. I hope it provides useful information.

Comment: When the data is coming from the database did you consider implementing it in SQL? Usually, it is much faster to run a complex SQL query than to load all records into memory and iterate over all records in Ruby.

Comment: Yes, I did and ideally, I'd love to move all the logic to SQL. However, the relations are not a simple `where` but they take into consideration multiple factors (and multiple tables) and I have no idea neither where to start from in SQL. So, for now, I think to complete it in Ruby and then, with time, move the logic to SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product) already returns a huge array containing all combinations. With 3 sub-arrays containing 150 items each, it returns a 150 × 150 × 150 = 3,375,000 element array. Calling `lazy` on that array won't speed up anything.

To make `product` calculate the Cartesian product lazily (i.e. one combination after the other), you simply have to (directly) pass a block to it:

```
first, *others = array

first.product(*others) do |combination|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks (again) for helping me out.